# write python code in single line

Tags: python

Can I write the following code in single line in python?

```
   t=int(input())
 while t:
    t-=1
    n=int(input())
    a=i=0
    while not(n&1<<i):
        i+=1
    while n&1<<i:
        n^=1<<i
        a=a*2+1
        i+=1
    print(n^1<<i)+a/2
```

If not, How can I write this piece of code in minimum possible lines?
(PS: I could reduce this in 6 lines, can it be any better)
My Solution
`t=int(input())
while t:
    t-=1;n=int(input());a=i=0
    while not(n&1<<i):i+=1
    while n&1<<i:n^=1<<i;a=a*2+1;i+=1
    print(n^1<<i)+a/2`
Thanks

Comment: First question - does `s1`, `s2`, `s7` affect the truth of `expr1`? Does `s3` affect `expr2`? Does `s4`, `s5`, or `s6` affect `expr3`? Without real code here, we can't even tell you whether some of your `while` loops are going to ever execute at all, much less whether execution will ever halt.

Comment: i think `s` stands for `statement`

Comment: @Beginner Yeah, I know, but that doesn't help us actually understand what would happen in the code. How can we condense it if we can't even know if `expr2` will ever be `True` in the first place, or, if it's `True` by then, whether it'll ever be `False`? If it's the former, we can condense it by just throwing away `while expr2`. If it's the latter, we can throw away `while expr3`. And either way the code will be fairly useless.

Comment: Wrote the actual code !! :)
Sorry for making it complicated for you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since pythons `list comprehensions` are turing complete and require no line breaks, *any* program can be written as a python oneliner.

If you enforce arbitrary restrictions (like "order of the statements" - what does that even mean? Execution order? First apperarance in sourcecode?), then the answer is: you can eliminate *some* linebreaks, but not all.

instead of

```
if x:
   do_stuff()
```

you can do:

```
if x: do_stuff()
```

instead of

```
x = 23
y = 42
```

you can do:

```
x,y = 23, 42
```

and instead of

```
 do_stuff()
 do_more_stuff()
```

you can do

```
do_stuff; do_more_stuff()
```

And if you *really, really have to*, you can `exec` a multi-line python program in one line, so your program becomes something like:

```
exec('''t=int(input())\nwhile t:\n t-=1;n=int(input());a=i=0\n while not(n&1<<i):i+=1\n while n&1<<i:n^=1<<i;a=a*2+1;i+=1\n print(n^1<<i)+a/2\n''')
```

But if you do this in "real" code, e.g. not just for fun, kittens die.

Comment: after 2 years of python I never knew semicolons actually did something! cool! basically useless, but cool!

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to collapse lines in Python very often, because you lose Python's famous simplicity and clarity that way. And you often cannot collapse lines, because indentation levels are used to define block structure / nesting.

But if you really want a condensed version:

```
print "s0"
while True:
    print "s1"; print "s2"
    while True: print "s3"
    while True: print "s4"; print "s5"; print "s6"
    print "s7"
```

(Where your expressions have been replaced with `True` for simplicity`)